# import com.firebase.client.Firebase in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application class to use Firebase in my complete application. However in the import line error occurs highlighting 'firebase' in red.
I have looked everywhere but cannot make out the problem.

**Code:**

```
package com.mobility.mobilityindia;
import android.app.Application;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;  <--- firebase is red here

public class MobilityIndia2 extends Application{
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);  <----  Firebase is red here
   }
```

**app level gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig
            {
                applicationId "com.mobility.mobilityindia"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    String googleSupportVersion = '26.+'
    String googlePlayServicesVersion = '11.0.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$googleSupportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$googleSupportVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$googleSupportVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**top level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you doing it !! are you following the latest android firebase tutorial  or gone through the documentation. You don't need to do that

Comment: Read official guideline at first .use `11.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is for an old version of the Firebase SDK (1.x or 2.x), while you're importing the latest version.

If you follow the [latest documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) or the latest [Android codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), you won't need the `Firebase.setAndroidContext()` anymore and will get imports that start with `com.google.firebase`.